# How to LEFT JOIN 3 Tables Without Getting Duplication in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

> select * from user

```
USERID  NAME    STATUS
1       AAA     Supervisor
2       BBB     Member
3       CCC     Admin
```

> select * from attendance

```
NO  DATE        SUPERVISOR  USERID  ADMIN
1   2019-12-07  1           2
2   2019-12-08  1           2
3   2019-12-09  1           2
4   2019-12-10  1           2
5   2019-12-11              1       CCC
```

> select * from detail

```
NO  USERID  ATTENDANCE  REASON
1   2       0           SICK
2   2       0           MEETING
3   2       0           NO REASON
4   2       0           SICK
5   1       0           MEETING
```

Here is the SQL that I've tried and the result

> SELECT u1.userid, a.date, u1.name, d.reason, u2.name as supervisor,
>   a.admin as admin FROM user u1 LEFT JOIN attendance a ON u1.userid =
>   a.userid LEFT JOIN user u2 ON a.supervisor = u2.userid LEFT JOIN detail d
>   ON u1.userid = d.userid WHERE d.attendance = 0
>   [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69dc1/2)

```
USERID  DATE        NAME    REASON        SUPERVISOR    ADMIN
2       2019-12-07  BBB     SICK          AAA
2       2019-12-08  BBB     MEETING       AAA
2       2019-12-09  BBB     NO REASON     AAA
2       2019-12-10  BBB     SICK          AAA
2       2019-12-07  BBB     SICK          AAA
2       2019-12-08  BBB     MEETING       AAA
2       2019-12-09  BBB     NO REASON     AAA
2       2019-12-10  BBB     SICK          AAA
2       2019-12-07  BBB     SICK          AAA
2       2019-12-08  BBB     MEETING       AAA
2       2019-12-09  BBB     NO REASON     AAA
2       2019-12-10  BBB     SICK          AAA
2       2019-12-07  BBB     SICK          AAA
2       2019-12-08  BBB     MEETING       AAA
2       2019-12-09  BBB     NO REASON     AAA
2       2019-12-10  BBB     SICK          AAA
1       2019-12-11  AAA     MEETING       NULL          CCC
```

The duplication works like this :
If the `attendance` or `detail` (I'm not sure) table has 4 data of member, it will loop for 4 times. If 5 data, then 5 times and so on..

The result I want :

```
USERID  DATE        NAME    REASON        SUPERVISOR    ADMIN
2       2019-12-07  BBB     SICK          AAA
2       2019-12-08  BBB     MEETING       AAA
2       2019-12-09  BBB     NO REASON     AAA
2       2019-12-10  BBB     SICK          AAA
1       2019-12-11  AAA     MEETING                     CCC
```

Thanks

Comment: You have no link between `attendance` and `detail` to indicate which `detail` row belongs to which `attendance` row. You need to add a field that links the two so the tables can be joined on it; this will prevent the duplication you are seeing.

Comment: You have to fix your table relation

Comment: @Nick Is there no way to fix my problem without adding a new table?

Comment: I've made this, check this out : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69dc1/2

Comment: There's no relationship between your dates and reason

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ What should I do to connect them?

Comment: your sqlfiddle doesn't have NO column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what we can do.

Let's generate row number for your `attendance` and `details` table based on `NO` column. I believe each time you insert 1 `detail` row corresponds to every `attendance` row based on user id.

```
SELECT u1.userid, a.date, u1.name, d.reason, u2.name as supervisor, a.admin as admin 
FROM user u1 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
      (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, 
      date,
      userid,
      admin,
      supervisor
  FROM
      attendance,
      (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
  ORDER BY 
      NO) a ON u1.userid = a.userid 
LEFT JOIN user u2 ON a.supervisor = u2.userid and u2.status='Supervisor'
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT 
      (@rn:=@rn + 1) AS num, 
      reason,
      userid,
      attendance
  FROM
      detail,
      (SELECT @rn:=0) AS t
  ORDER BY 
      NO ) d ON u1.userid = d.userid and d.num = a.num
where d.attendance = 0
```

see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69dc1/19).

Comment: Thank you! Even though the sql is quite long.. XD

Answer (score 1):

You have no link between attendance and detail to indicate which detail row belongs to which attendance row. You need to add a field that links the two so the tables can be joined on it; this will prevent the duplication you are seeing. One way to fix this would be to add a `DATE` column to `detail`. See this [demo on SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9495b/1)

```
SELECT u1.userid, a.date, u1.name, d.reason, u2.name as supervisor, a.admin as admin 
FROM user u1 
LEFT JOIN attendance a ON u1.userid = a.userid 
LEFT JOIN user u2 ON a.supervisor = u2.userid 
LEFT JOIN detail d ON u1.userid = d.userid AND d.date = a.date
WHERE d.attendance = 0
```

Output

```
userid  date        name    reason      supervisor  admin
2       2019-12-07  BBB     SICK        AAA     
2       2019-12-08  BBB     MEETING     AAA     
2       2019-12-09  BBB     NO REASON   AAA     
2       2019-12-10  BBB     SICK        AAA     
1       2019-12-11  AAA     MEETING     (null)      CCC
```